# Replace REGEX variable with htmlentities?

Tags: php, regex

I have the following bit of code as the replacement in preg_replace

```
"<div style="font-style:italic;margin:8px 6px">$2</div>"
```

**Is there a way to wrap htmlentities() around $2?**

Comment: Double-check your quotes, the syntax highlighting suggests something is not right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
function replace($matches) {
    return '<div style="font-style:italic;margin:8px 6px">' 
      . htmlentities($matches[2]) . '</div>';
}

preg_replace_callback('/pattern/', 'replace', $string);
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about that handy little function. :)